# Power BI Question - Creating Week Over Week % change based on ISOWeek index in a table

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset that contains multiple dimensions with metrics and trying to create Week over week change based on "ISOweek" indicator created as a separate column.

So the original dataset looks like,

dimensions [Date, product, location] and metrics [budget allocated]

The challenge I cannot figure out is that

I created a table in the dashboard that is supposed to have,

dimensions [ISOindice] and Metrics [Spend, Spend Week over week change %]

```
To do this, I created ISO week indicator, starting Monday using the below formula.
ISOindice = dataset[ISO Year] & "-" & FORMAT(dataset[Week Number], "00")
Where, Week Number = WEEKNUM(dataset[date], 21)
And, ISO Year = YEAR(dataset[date] + 26 - dataset[Week Number])
and put this dimension into the table I created above with spend and WoW spend % metrics
```

However it`s not picking up the number correctly.

I tried using things like Earlier or MAX(ISOindice) etc..
but it looks like because there are multiple rows existing for a single ISOindice element in the original dataset (due to product and location columns..), it`s not working.